# XCode environment variables vs property list for TEST and PROD

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plist

I am somewhat noobish to IOS development and wanted to find the best way to manage my environment variables depending on the build scheme of my app.

So if I perform a DEBUG build, I want my app to retrieve all data from server say

```
http://debugserver1.blah.com
```

And likewise, if I perform a TEST build, I want my app to retrieve all data from server say

```
http://testserver2.blah.com
```

And for prod

```
http://prodserver.blah.com
```

I am sure this is an uncommon scenario and am trying to figure out what is the BEST way to approach this. I've looked into Environment variables, but I don't think that makes sense, so I am leaning to pLists.

Can you guys assist in helping me associate certain pLists to certain scheme builds?

Comment: I have to ask the obvious, have you considered using conditional compilation with `#ifdef`?

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the hints. Yeah we are doing that at the moment, but we are doing that for EVERY controller which makes it hideous. Maybe the question I should be asking, (if that is the right approach), is how to make these compilation constants accessible through ALL of my controllers, rather than just scoped within the single controller instead.

Comment: I suppose you could have a common `#include` file that each of your controllers uses, which contains the common definitions for things like server name based on compile-time defines.

Comment: I like the idea Greg. Is this standard practice using a common #include? P.S - have you got some snippets of code to assist?

Comment: @alwinc Did either of the answers below work for you?

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up using servername.h with ifdefined(DEBUG) conditions as set in the Xcode Scheme setups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common scenario, and easily handled. By default, when you create a new project, `DEBUG` is `#defined` for the **Debug** build configuration, but not for the **Release** configuration. For your **Test** configuration, you'll probably copy **Debug** and add a `#define` for `TEST`

I'd probably go down the route of creating a manager class to handle your API calls, and add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * baseURLString;
```

Then in your class's init method:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
self.baseURLString = "http://debugserver1.blah.com";
#elif defined(TEST) 
self.baseURLString = "http://testserver1.blah.com";
#else
self.baseURLString = "http://prodserver1.blah.com";
#endif
```

Then use the `baseURLString` to construct URLs to make your API calls.

Comment: I see so you are suggesting to create 1 Manager Class to handle ALL of the API calls?

Comment: That's the way I tend to do it... usually a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a definition file that is `#include`d into each of your source files. For example:

### servername.h

```
#define DEBUG_BUILD
//#define TEST_BUILD
//#define PRODUCTION_BUILD

#if defined(DEBUG_BUILD)
    #define SERVER_NAME "http://debugserver1.blah.com"
#elif defined(TEST_BUILD)
    #define SERVER_NAME "http://testserver2.blah.com"
#elif defined(PRODUCTION_BUILD)
    #define SERVER_NAME "http://prodserver.blah.com"
#else
    #error Must define build type
#endif
```

Then, in each of your source files where you need to use `SERVER_NAME`, at the top do:

```
#include "servername.h"
```

The above will work, but you would need to edit `servername.h` to change the build type. A better way is to remove the `#define` statements from `servername.h`, and use the build settings in Xcode to define the build type. To do this, go to your Build Settings and scroll down until you find the Preprocessing section. A default project looks like this:

[image]

In that section, for each type of build, you can add `DEBUG_BUILD`, `TEST_BUILD`, or `PRODUCTION_BUILD` as needed.

Comment: regarding the **better way**, would that be similar to

`#ifdef DEBUG  
    #define SERVER_NAME "http://debugserver1.blah.com"  
#else  
    #define SERVER_NAME "http://prodserver.blah.com"  
#endif`

Comment: @alwinc: If you use `#ifdef` / `#else`, you're limited to two choices unless you start nesting them, which is ugly. If you use `#if defined(...)` you can also use `#elif defined(...)` which looks much better.